# In R, why am I getting "Error in [: (subscript) logical subscript too long"?

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, lapply, tibble

The below MWE Code 1 works fine, in calculating the sumproduct of 2 columns of numbers, with the sumproduct input matrix expanding horizontally to accommodate additional sumproduct scenarios.

MWE Code 2 below is a modification of MWE Code 1 to make the input matrix vertically expandable too, so the user can add rows of elements to be summed in the sumproduct calculation. When I run MWE Code 2, the code crashes giving me "Error in [: (subscript) logical subscript too long".

Why am I getting this error?

The images below illustrate the issue.

MWE Code 1:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sumProd <- function(a, b) { # a = periods, b = matrix inputs
  c    <- rep(NA, a)
  c[]  <- sum(b[,1]) %*% sum(b[,2])
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'X-axis periods:', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  matrixInput(
    "myMatrixInput",
    label = "Two columns to sumproduct are paired under each scenario heading:",
    value =  matrix(c(1, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE,  delta = 2, names = TRUE,  delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, delta = 1, names = FALSE, delete = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$myMatrixInput, {
    tmpMatrix <- input$myMatrixInput
    
    # Remove any empty matrix columns
    empty_columns <- sapply(tmpMatrix, function(x) all(is.na(x) | x == ""))
    tmpMatrix <- tmpMatrix[, !empty_columns, drop=FALSE]
    
    # Assign column header names
    colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario", rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix), each = 2, length.out = ncol(tmpMatrix)))
    
    isolate( # isolate update to prevent infinite loop
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "myMatrixInput", value = tmpMatrix)
    )
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$myMatrixInput)/2),
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$myMatrixInput)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = sumProd(input$periods,input$myMatrixInput[1,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(
      x = X,
      y = Y,
      colour = as.factor(Scenario)
    ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

MWE Code 2:

```
sumProd <- function(a, b) { # a = periods, b = matrix inputs
  c    <- rep(NA, a)
  c[]  <- sum(b[,1]) %*% sum(b[,2])
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'X-axis periods:', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  matrixInput(
    "myMatrixInput",
    label = "Two columns to sumproduct are paired under each scenario heading:",
    value =  matrix(c(1, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE,  delta = 2, names = TRUE,  delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 1, names = FALSE, delete = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  sanitizedMat <- reactiveVal() # < for vertical matrix expansion
  
  observeEvent(input$myMatrixInput, {
    if(any(colnames(input$myMatrixInput) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$myMatrixInput
      
      # Remove any empty matrix columns
      empty_columns <- sapply(tmpMatrix, function(x) all(is.na(x) | x == ""))
      tmpMatrix <- tmpMatrix[, !empty_columns, drop=FALSE]
      
      # Assign column header names
      colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario", rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix), each = 2, length.out = ncol(tmpMatrix)))
      
      isolate( # isolate update to prevent infinite loop
        updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "myMatrixInput", value = tmpMatrix)
      )
    }
    sanitizedMat(na.omit(input$myMatrixInput))
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(sanitizedMat())/2),
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(sanitizedMat())[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = sumProd(input$periods,sanitizedMat()[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(
      x = X,
      y = Y,
      colour = as.factor(Scenario)
    ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to simply eliminate automated matrix empty column deletion under the single `observeEvent()` and modify UDF `sumProd()` to ignore NA's (added `na.rm = T` to `sum()` in `sumProd()`). NA's will arise in the matrix when sub-columns (groupings of 2 columns under each scenario header) are of unequal lengths, so ignoring the NA's resolves the issue. Also removed UDF `sanitizedMat()` and automated empty column deletion feature in MWE2 to simplify.

Revised code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sumProd <- function(a, b) { # a = periods, b = matrix inputs
  c    <- rep(NA, a)
  c[]  <- sum(b[,1], na.rm = T) %*% sum(b[,2],na.rm = T) # Added na.rm = T
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'X-axis periods:', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  matrixInput(
    "myMatrixInput",
    label = "Two columns to sumproduct are paired under each scenario heading:",
    value =  matrix(c(1, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE,  delta = 2, names = TRUE,  delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 1, names = FALSE, delete = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$myMatrixInput, {
    if(any(colnames(input$myMatrixInput) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$myMatrixInput
      colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMatrix)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "myMatrixInput", value = tmpMatrix))
      }
    input$myMatrixInput
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$myMatrixInput)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
         function(i){
             tibble(
               Scenario = colnames(input$myMatrixInput)[i*2-1],
               X = seq_len(input$periods),
               Y = sumProd(input$periods,input$myMatrixInput[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
             )
          }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(
      x = X,
      y = Y,
      colour = as.factor(Scenario)
    ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```